# django-tables2: Table.render_Foo naming

Tags: django, django-tables2

I got the following Table and want to implement a `render_foo()` function for the `modelField.ST` and `modelField.ZF` fields.

```
class MyTable(Table):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('modelField.ST', 'modelField.ZF', 'score')
```

How are they named?

`def render_modelField_ST(self, record)`

and

`def render_modelField__ST(self, record)`

did not work

Thank you!

Comment: Please take care to format your code examples, it really helps those who want to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You must define an explicit column in your custom table class and use its name to create the `render_FOO()` method:

```
import django_tables2 as tables

class MyTable(tables.Table):
    st = tables.Column(accessor="modelField.ST")
    zf = tables.Column(accessor="modelField.ZT")

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('modelField.ST', 'modelField.ZF', 'score')

    def render_st(self, record, value):
        return value

    def render_zt(self, record, value):
        return value
```